# Disable <li> tag based on value of a key in web.config file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, web-config

C#

```
string fblink = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook"];
if (fblink == "")
{ 
  //need code to disable <li>   
}
```

HTML

```
    <div >
       <ul>
          <li id="face">
              <a id="fb" runat="server" target="_blank" href="<%$ AppSettings:facebook %>"></a> 
           </li> 
    </div>
```

In web.config file added a key named facebook with value.
 
If this value is empty the li tag should disable

Comment: Krishna I want to disable the <li id="face"> tag i.e the contents in li tag should not be visible if the value is empty

Comment: `fb.Visible = false` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `<li>` in back-end means you should give `runat="server"` as tag attribute. if so The `li` will looks like the following:

```
<li id="face" runat="server"> .. </li>
```

So that you can access them like this:

```
if (fblink == "")
{ 
   face.Visible=false;
}
```

By using javascript:

```
var fblink = '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook"].ToString() %>';
if (fblink == "")
{ 
  var liElement =  document.GetElementByID("face");
  liElement.style.display = 'none'; 
}
```